# Directly connecting a internal node of a remote server

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, terminal

I was trying to open files like `.ipynb` via terminal command line (command: `code`) on the remote server in VSCode.

But `code` is not in `PATH`, so I used

```
~/.vscode-server/bin/b3e4e68a0bc097f0ae7907b217c1119af9e03435/bin/remote-cli/code a.ipynb
```

and got this error:

> Command is only available in WSL or inside a Visual Studio Code
> terminal.

This command was entered after I SSH node1 on the remote server.
So I guess I need to directly connect to the internal node on the remote server so that I can use `code` command to open files in VSCode.

To make it clearer, here's what I did:

Me -> SSH remote server -> SSH node1 (I want to open `.ipynb` files in this node because it has GPUs while the root node does not).

So I guess the solution is:

Me -> SSH remote server node1

How can I do this?

Comment: what precisely is "node1"? I don;t believe this is standard terminology related to an SSH feature. could be a gateway or a jump box or something completely different.  Please edit your question to clarify your request, and provide information about the layout of the remote network/hosts please.

Comment: @FrankThomas I am not quite sure about the layout of the remote network. What I know is I could connect to the root node of the server. After connection, by 'ssh node1' in the command line, I could enter the computing node1. Node 1, I think can be seen as a new computer, which has its own CPUs and GPUs. Is there anyway I can check the layout? Thanks a lot!

Comment: so it sounds like this is a jump server. the point of implementing them is that the shell on the jump server must be used to connect to the systems inside the network to which it is connected. It sounds like what you want would be better served by connecting to a VPN on that network, so you can open a remote shell directly on the server `node1` but that means that the network admins of the remote site would need to implement one.  otherwise you will be stuck connecting through two shells to reach the destination.